# Using mciSendString in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, mcisendstring

I’m trying to use the mciSendString function to open and close the cd tray in Qt. Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
MCIERROR mciSendString(LPCTSTR lpszCommand, LPTSTR lpszReturnString, UINT cchReturn, HANDLE hwndCallback);
void OpenCD()
{
    mciSendString((LPCTSTR)"set cdaudio door open",(LPTSTR)NULL, (UINT)0, (HANDLE)NULL);
}
void CloseCD()
{
    mciSendString((LPCTSTR)"set cdaudio door closed",(LPTSTR)NULL, (UINT)0, (HANDLE)NULL);
}
```

But I get this error: “ undefined reference to `mciSendStringW(wchar_t const*, wchar_t*, unsigned int, void*)' ”
How can I fix this error and use the mciSendString function without any problem?

Comment: I downloaded the Windows SDK and added to the project the reference to library. Solution link: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19620/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add one of the next lines to pro-file:

```
LIBS += path_to_lib/Winmm.lib
```

or

```
LIBS += path_to_lib/Winmm.dll
```

Also you can include Mmsystem.h and Windows.h

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For example:
Pro file inludes link to lib-file from installed SDK:

```
LIBS += $$quote(C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.0A\\Lib\\WinMM.lib)
```

In cpp-file:

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "mmsystem.h"
//MCIERROR mciSendString(LPCTSTR lpszCommand, LPTSTR lpszReturnString, UINT cchReturn, HANDLE hwndCallback);
...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
   mciSendString((LPCTSTR)"set cdaudio door open",(LPTSTR)NULL, (UINT)0, (HWND__*)0);
}
```